# get highest version from a remote metadata xml file

Tags: linux, xml, shell, gitlab, continuous-integration

I have a remote file in artifactory metadata.xml with below information

```
   
      <version>3.1.2.0</version>
      <version>3.1.2.506</version> 
      <version>3.1.2.507</version> 
      <version>3.1.2.508</version>
```

if my branch name is release/3.1.2 , by parsing above xml file , shell command need to return 3.1.2.508 which is latest version.

Can any one help. This is inside gitlab ci cd pipeline, trying to bump up version based on latest version. I do not have option to use
`<latest></latest>`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If `xmllint` is available (as it is in most linux distros as libxml tools) this command will get the last version from the provided sample

```
xmllint --xpath '//version[last()]/text()' tmp.xml 
3.1.2.508
```

If versions are not in order

```
xmllint --xpath '//version/text()' tmp.xml | sort --version-sort | tail -n1
```

Package containing `xmllint` (on my local distro,i.e.)

```
rpm -qf /usr/bin/xmllint 
libxml2-tools-2.9.14-150400.5.22.1.x86_64
```

Alternative with a `gawk` one-liner

```
gawk 'BEGIN{RS="\\s*<[/]?version>"}{ if(NR>1 && $0 ~ /([0-9]+\.){3,3}/){ver[NR-1]=$0 }} END{n=asort(ver); print ver[n]}' tmp.xml
```

Given

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Parent>
  <Field1 type="int">7933</Field1>
  <Field2>9.26</Field2>
  <Field3>xxx</Field3>
  <Field4>yyy</Field4>
  
           <version>3.1.2.507</version><version>3.1.2.0</version>
      <version>3.1.2.506</version> 

      <version>3.1.2.508</version>

  <version>3.1.1.508</version>
</Parent>
```

Result

```
3.1.2.508
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`xq` utility](https://github.com/sibprogrammer/xq) to query xml files

```bash
filename="metadata.xml"
xpath_query="version"
latest="$(xq -x "${xpath_query}" $filename | sort -rn | head -n 1)"
echo $latest
```

```
3.1.2.508
```

`xq -x "${xpath_query}" $filename` will extract the text of the queried XML elements from the file. This is piped into `sort -rn` to sort these using natural (`-n`) sorting in reverse (`-r`) order, then we take the top line of the sorted output by piping to `head -n 1`.

---

If you're relatively confident in the contents of the file and format of the version string, you could *probably* get away with just using a grep expression instead of needing to actually parse XML:

```bash
latest="$(grep -oP '\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+' < metadata.xml | sort -rn | head -n 1)"
echo $latest
```

```
3.1.2.508
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sed command

```
sed -n '/<version>/{s/.*<version>//;s/<\/version.*//;p;}' metadata.xml | sort -V | tail -1
```